# zlib not detected by `gem install redis`

Tags: ruby, redis, zlib

Having issue with making gem install to detect zlib.

I'm trying to install redis api for ruby. This needs zlib. Installed zlib through yum - `sudo yum install zlib`. Installation is successful (as below).

```
[~]$ sudo yum install zlib
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, versionlock
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: server>.com
 * epel: server>.com
 * extras: <server>.com
 * hp: server>.com
 * updates: server>.com
Package zlib-1.2.7-17.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

But, `gem install redis` couldn't detect zlib. I get below error when installing redis api.

```
[~]$ sudo gem install redis
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

**Any reason why gem install couldn't detect the zlib?**

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're missing the `devel` package for zlib. `rpm -qa | grep zlib` should produce output like the following:

```
# rpm -qa | grep zlib
zlib-devel-1.2.7-15.el7.x86_64
zlib-1.2.7-15.el7.x86_64
```

You'll want to include `zlib-devel` and then try re-installing the redis gem. If this doesn't solve your issue, please include the output of `gem install redis --verbose` in your question.

Comment: `rpm -qa | grep zlib ->
zlib-1.2.7-17.el7.x86_64
 zlib-devel-1.2.7-17.el7.x86_64`

Comment: zlib-devel exists.

Comment: @barath can you do a `gem install redis --verbose` and add the full output to your question?